# F# type mismatch while calling function

Tags: f#

This code

```
let rec readNLines n list =
 if n = 0 then
  list
 else 
  readNLines(n-1,readInt()::list)
```

ends with

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a 'a but given a 'a -> 'a    
The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and
''a -> 'a' (using built-in F# compiler)
```

but runs ok when last line is changed to

```
  readNLines(n-1,(readInt()::list))
```

or

```
  readNLines(n-1)(readInt()::list)
```

Question is: Why? :|

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only the last version can work, because `readNLines` takes two arguments, but

```
readNLines (n - 1, readInt() :: list)
```

passes only one argument (which is a tuple consisting of an `int` and the `list`).

```
readNLines (n - 1) (readInt() :: list)
```

passes them as two separate arguments - the difference here is using the comma (tuple) and space (two arguments).

By the way, that becomes much clearer when you use more whitespace (as I did), because the individual elements are easier to identify.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at these two functions:

```
> let f1 a b = a + b

val f1 : a:int -> b:int -> int

> let f2 (a, b) = a + b

val f2 : a:int * b:int -> int
```

As you can see, they have slightly different types. In function `f1` you partially apply the arguments (you'll see the term 'curried function' used here),  in function `f2` you pass in a tuple of arguments in one "go", or you can think of it as only ever having a single argument (an 'uncurried' function).

What you're doing is defining a function `f1` style, but later calling it `f2` style, which confuses the compiler.