# what does this error mean, and how to fix it?

Tags: f#

Here's my code

```
let rec Interest a b c =
    if (c=0) then b else Interest(a ((1.0+a)*b) (c-1));;
```

The error is:

> if (c=0) then b else Interest(a ((1.0+a)*b) (c-1));;
>
> -------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> stdin(2,26): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
>       'a     but given a
>       'a -> int -> 'a     The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and ''a -> int -> 'a'
>   >

Comment: Possible duplicate of [F# type mismatch while calling function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236509/f-type-mismatch-while-calling-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've defined `Interest` as a function that takes three arguments but what you pass doesn't match that. The way it's written, you're only passing in a single argument to the recursive call to Interest - the parenthesized expression `a ((1.0=a)*b) (c-1)`. Here, `a` is inferred to be a function of two arguments, `((1.0=a)*b)` and `(c-1)`.

Long story short, this throws off the type inference algorithm, until it gives up saying that it can't get a hang of what type to give to `Interest`.

What you want is this:

```
let rec Interest a b c =
    if (c=0) then b else Interest a ((1.0=a)*b) (c-1)
```

You'll also have a problem with `(1.0=a)`. This evaluates to a boolean value that you later want to multiply with `b`. Not sure what the intent is, but you might be looking for something like `(if 1.0 = a then 1 else 0)`?

Unlike C-like languages that support implicit conversions between "bools" and ints, F# requires you to make all your conversions explicit to ensure correctness (this goes for converting between numeric types as well).

Comment: It's not a tuple. There is no comma. It was treating `a` as a function of two arguments.

Comment: Thanks, so putting parentheses around the 3 arguments caused the problem, but is there no way to put parentheses around the argument  ... to redundantly make clear 3 args are being passed in?   P.S.  Edited the (1.0=a) .. it was a typo

Comment: No, the parentheses change the meaning here. You can write this function in a way where you would *need* to put the parentheses around arguments, but that would be a function with a slightly different type (and usage characteristics). See here about difference between curried and uncurried functions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32236855/679898 (also, that makes your question a duplicate ;))

Comment: That makes sense .. so ... "Interest a b c" takes 3 arguments, whereas "Interest (a b c)" takes 1 argument, which is a tuple?

Comment: Yes, except it's `Interest (a, b, c)` - with commas to separate tuple elements (as pointed out in an earlier comment).